# Objective C Properties vs. arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't quite understand Objective C and how does Properties and arguments work.
I seem to run into Object-Oriented design mistake: I'm trying to pass in information about the state of an object to one of it’s methods. Can someone explain to me how does this code works with Person class that took as arguments their firstName and lastName:

```
Person.m
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person
- (NSString *)fullNameWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName;
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
}
@end
```

How can I fix this mistake?
I tried to started to fix this design mistake and added the self to Name but it keeps giving me unexpected error. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Can you show what you're doing that's causing the error as well as the exact error message?

Comment: While the semicolon is non-standard and confusing, it's perfectly valid objective-C syntax @RoboticCat

Comment: @nhgrif: Thanks for the info; you learn something new everyday.  Comment deleted.

Comment: @RoboticCat Yea, I only learned that a couple days ago myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what you're doing doesn't really make a whole lot of sense.  The method you posted is no different then just calling `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` in place of where ever you're calling this method.  You don't modify anything within the class.  You don't retrieve data from the class.

---

Assuming a `Person` class is intended to hold a person's name, your header file would likely have a few properties as such:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *lastName;
@property (readonly,nonatomic,strong) NSString *fullName;
```

The `.m` file would contain a few different types of methods.

- `init` methods
- `factory` methods
- `accessor` methods for any of the property accessors you want to override
- And other miscellaneous methods you might need depending on what you're doing with the class.

---

Given the properties we're assuming were declared in the header, you can set or retrieve the first name, set or retrieve the last name.  You could also attempt retrieving the last name, but without any logic in the `.m` to set it (and it's readonly outside the `.m`), it'd just return `nil`.  Without putting anything in the `.m` file, the following is all valid:

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
person.firstName = @"John";
person.lastName = @"Doe";
NSLog(@"%@ %@", person.firstName, person.lastName); //prints "John Doe"
```

---

Since `fullName` would actually be merely a concatenation of first name and last name, we can override the getter for it (wouldn't have a setter as we marked it `readonly`) in order to prevent our class from keep an instance variable.  So that would look like this:

```
-(NSString*)fullName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}
```

Now the `fullName` property builds a `fullName` string on the fly and returns that instead of keeping a separate variable in memory for this.

---

A method called `fullNameWithFirstName:lastName:` would seem to fit as a `factory` method, but per naming conventions, it should actually be called `personWithFirstName:lastName:`.

It should actually look something like this:

```
+(instancetype)personWithFirstName:(NSString*)firstName 
    lastName:(NSString*)lastName {
    return [[Person alloc] initWithFirstName:firstName lastName:lastName];
}
```

So it'd merely invoke a designated initializer, which might look like this:

```
-(id)initWithFirstName:(NSString*)firstName lastName:(NSString*)lastName {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.firstName = firstName;
        self.lastName = lastName;
    }
    return self;
}
```

With this code, you can do this:

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Steve" lastName:@"Jobs"];
Person *person2 = [Person fullNameWithFirstName:@"Bill" lastName:@"Gates"];
```

Both ways will make `person` or `person2` an object of type `Person` which will return correct values for calls like this:

```
person.firstName
person.lastName
person.fullName
```

Comment: Wouldn't a factory method be named `personWithFirstName:lastName:`?  You're returning a `Person` not a `FullName`.

Comment: @AaronBrager Hmm, yea.  I was keeping his original method name, but you're right.  I updated the answer changing the method name, but leaving a comment explanation for why it's changed.

Comment: in `personWithFirstName:lastName:` you should really do `[[self class] alloc]` etc... to make subclasses be able to override the method.

Comment: @Lance Since this is a class method, you can just use `[self alloc]`, since `self` represents the class in class methods.  (Your point remains correct.)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help on the method.